# How to change value of second duplicate in row

Tags: python, pandas

I have not been able to find an answer to the following online. Your valuable help would be much appreciated.

I have a `DataFrame` like this with 20k rows:

```
ID            Date           Country
2008-0001     2008-01-02     India
2008-0001     2008-01-02     France
2008-0002     2008-01-03     USA
```

I want to take all the duplicates in `ID` such as in rows 1 and 2 and then increment the second `ID` to the highest number after the dash.

So for instance because there is already `2008-0002` (assume that `0002` is the highest number after the dash in that column for that year) then I want to increment to one above that so one of the duplicate id values 2008-0001 would become 2008-0003.

I can identify and drop duplicates using the following code

```
drop_duplicate_df = train_df.drop_duplicates(['ID'])
```

but this is not what I need.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this will get it done:

```
isdup = df.duplicated(subset=['ID1', 'ID2'])

dups, uniques = df[isdup], df[~isdup]

ids = ['ID1', 'ID2']
for i, row in dups.iterrows():
    while (row[ids] == uniques[ids]).all(axis=1).any():
        row.loc['ID2'] += 1
    uniques = uniques.append(row)

id1 = uniques.ID1.astype(str)
id2 = uniques.ID2.astype(str).str.zfill(4)
uniques.loc[:, 'ID'] = id1 + '-' + id1

uniques.drop(['ID1', 'ID2'], axis=1, inplace=True)

print uniques.sort_index()

          ID        Date Country
0  2008-0001  2008-01-02   India
1  2008-0003  2008-01-02  France
2  2008-0002  2008-01-03     USA
```

Answer (score 0):

The below works with the sample data, and assumes you have data for several years that you all want to relabel according to the same logic:

```
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date) # to datetime to extract years
years = df.groupby(df.Date.dt.year) # analysis per year
new_df = pd.DataFrame()
for year, data in years:
    data.loc[data.duplicated(subset='ID'), 'ID'] = '{0}-{1}'.format(year, str(int(df.ID.max().split('-')[1]) + 1).zfill(4))
    new_df = pd.concat([new_df, data])
```

to get:

```
          ID       Date Country
0  2008-0001 2008-01-02   India
1  2008-0003 2008-01-02  France
2  2008-0002 2008-01-03     USA
```

Comment: Thanks so much Stefan. Im trying to apply this to my dataset but it's not quite working and I'm trying to figure out why - perhaps because I have some null values. I'm just trying to work on fitting this to the data.

Comment: No error message but the duplicates are not changed. I'm just going through step by step and printing the output - thanks again!

Comment: The code relies on `Date` being converted to `datetime`. Other than that not sure why this wouldn't work, I think I just straight away copied your sample data.

Comment: Hi again, I get the following warning, but unsure if this is what's causing the error: C:\Users\i\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:461: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  self.obj[item] = s

Comment: when I just print years on it's own, I get the following error:

Comment: <pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x08303B70>

Comment: ID Start End Country Location Type Sub_Type Names Killed Affected Cost International support
    4321 2003-0628 2003-12-25 2003-12-25 Costa Rica Along Panama border Earthquake (seismic activity) Earthquake (ground shaking) NaN 2.0 135.0 NaN 0.000
11907 2003-0628 2003-12-25 2003-12-25 Panama Puerto Armuelles Earthquake (seismic activity) Earthquake (ground shaking) NaN 2.0 1075.0 NaN 1066.174

Comment: The warning doesn't matter in this context. Need to print `year` inside the `for` loop, not `years`, that's indeed the `groupby` object itself, not one of the groups we are trying to look at. You can also print out `data` inside the loop to see if there's anything different than it should be, like missing vals etc

Comment: HI and thanks again. Ok, so my first mistake was not simplifying date to year. That was easily fixed using df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date,'%Y' )and I got 47 rows remaining. That is because some have more than one duplicate. I thought, incorrectly, that I could simply run the script again but I've done something wrong. Now I have 17000 duplicates! Trying to figure out why. Probably something simple. But wondering how can I run an inner function to change all duplicates in one go and increment all of them.

Comment: Not sure why you would have to simplify the date. `.groupby('df.Date.dt.year')` already makes sure the grouping only looks at the year values - as long as the column is of type `datetime`. The current code also picks out all duplicates (per year) at once and assigns the highest ID + 1.